# None of the other questions about snapping answer my question

Tags: snapping

I'd like these faces to snap together and they will not do so.  What am I doing wrong?[image]

Here is a gyazo link to a gif since I cannot figure out how to upload the mp4.

https://gyazo.com/c1ac2c6276ab5590c46738b689ed5ef1

Comment: Keep moving until the mouse cursor is over the face you want to snap to, not just until the faces meet. You can press G (grab tool) instead of the move tool to make it easier to move the object while "aiming " the mouse cursor. It can be a bit tricky to get it right, but it should snap when your MOUSE is over the face you want to snap to.

Comment: Thank you - I knew it was something simple like that since I had had this work in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snapping doesn't work based on distance ... It works when the faces (of other objects) comes under the mouse cursor. or so i Guess.. Check this below screengrab. I've moved my mouse over the steps, (adjusted the view to make it happen)

[image]

Here's my snap settings.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Please add a screenshot of your snapping settings, it could be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @JachymMichal - thanks for the suggestion. Added.